# Ruby Gem dependency versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, dependencies, gemspecs

I finish my first gem. I want to publish it, but i have dependencies question.

My gem has dependency of active_record(~> 4.1);

And development_dependencies: rake, bundler, sqlite;

How can I determine minimal and maximal versions of rake, bundler, sqlite that will works with my gem?